# Why "The pump don't work ..." correct here?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, metaphors, proverbs

> "The pump **don't** work 'Cause the vandals took the handle."
>
> -- Bob Dylan

I came across this sentence in a book. It looks like the author quoted that sentence written by Bob Dylan -- who might be a famous person I guess.

I feel "**The pump don't work**" doesn't look right because **pump** is a countable noun and it should take a single verb form, *doesn't*.

On the other hand,  the sentence seems pretty straight forward and I don't understand why it's so famous that deserves to be quoted by the author. Maybe, there is a underlying meaning, which I haven't gotten yet?

P.S. The book's name is *The Long Walk*, by *Stephen King*.

Comment: This is ungrammatical in standard English. It reflects an uneducated speaker and a dialect where **don't** is also valid for third-person singular. Bob Dylan is an American songwriter and performer who won the Nobel Prize for literature. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-39429032

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['He don't have knowledge ' vs 'He doesn't have knowledge'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34571/he-dont-have-knowledge-vs-he-doesnt-have-knowledge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Don’t" used in the third person singular by Bob Dylan is what we would call a “poetic licence” probably meant to have the desired (linguistic/dramatic) effect in the song lyrics:

Anyway:

> [Don't](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/don-t-and-doesn-t) is occasionally used in American English speech and in historical writing as a contraction of does not (as in, "He don't know where he is going."), but this use is now considered improper and should be avoided. ***Remember that in modern speech and writing, don't cannot be used in the third person singular.***

(M-W)

Comment: Is there any underlying meaning for that sentence?

Comment: @dan - lyrics are always open to interpretations. It just looks literal  to me.

Comment: @dan The song is [Subterranean Homesick Blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subterranean_Homesick_Blues). A lot of the song seems to be references to the drug culture and counterculture of the time it was written. I'm not sure of the meaning of the sentence in context, as the lyrics are disjointed. The immediately preceding line is "don't want to be a bum you better chew gum".

Comment: Bob Dylan was famous most for his lyrics (certainly not his voice), of which he wrote an enormous quantity.  The lyrics are usually creative and flow well, but don't necessarily have any special meaning, except perhaps as a tortured metaphor that no one else would understand without explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As a singer/songwriter, Bob Dylan is admired for his lyrics.  He wrote a vast number of songs, some of them quite long and full of fairly dense narrative -- or, in many cases, clever-sounding gibberish:

> Better jump down a manhole, light yourself a candle
>   Don't wear sandals, try to avoid the scandals
>   Don't want to be a bum, you better chew gum
>   The pump don't work 'cause the vandals took the handles

Here we have a stanza full of interesting but generally meaningless rhymes:

> *manhole : candle*
>   *sandals : scandals*
>   *bum : gum*
>   *vandals : handles*.

I wouldn't overthink this, as quite a lot of Dylan's songs contain similar phrases.  It's just his style.

As for your original question: It's not uncommon for English speakers to fail to conjugate the verb, although this is usually interpreted as either "country" or "poorly educated" (or both) depending on the context. Examples:

> She **don't** like fish.
>
> They **is** going to the store.
>
> He **write** to his momma every week.

Writers and songwriters who like to appeal to the "common man" (such as Dylan) will often use this kind of dialect, even though it's clear from their facility with the language that they know proper grammar.

As with any dialect, I do not recommend mimicking this *unless* you fully understand how to use it and the full cultural context.  There is a fine line between *imitation* and *mockery*, and some people might take offense.