# Regarding usage of "doesn't " and "don't"

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

I have heard sentences like 
*"He don't like this ."*
Or
*"He don't know this ."*

Shouldn't it be 
*"He doesn't like this."*
And
*"He doesn't know this."*

Why with singular person we use *"don't"* and not *"doesn't"* ?

Comment: I've only heard the usage of "he don't" from two groups of people: 1) young children (including myself at an early age) who are still trying to learn all the nuances of the language and 2) persons from lower socio-economic backgrounds, who regrettably tend to be under-educated and prone to a very informal and low-register grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it should be "He doesn't like this." Sometimes people use it incorrectly on purpose or in an attempt to sound like a redneck. You'll also hear it used in African American Vernacular English (AAVE).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons you might encounter this. These include:

1) The speaker/writer is a learner who does not know the correct way to conjugate the verb.

2) The speaker/writer speaks a dialect that doesn't emphasize correct conjugation.

3) The speaker/writer is trying to invoke a certain mood (this could be anything from rural mountain folk to urban people on the streets).

In short, the usage may be due to a lack of education, or it may be quite deliberate.

A [recent ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182032/why-the-pump-dont-work-correct-here) asked something similar about a Bob Dylan lyric, and someone pointed out that Dylan has been awarded the Nobel Prize for Literature.