# Conjugation in persons and numbers

Tags: conjunctions

I've noticed that in some cases music artists (and maybe someone else too) use conjugation that is technically wrong, however it's obviously done on purpose. Here are some examples from The Weeknd - Six Feet Under:
"*She don't* get emotional", "*She don't* depend on anybody", "*She lick* it up"..

I guess that might be for rhythmical purposes, but I would like to find out if it changes a sense somehow or some feeling. Because if I try to do that thing in my language it will not sound native.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's informal dialect. The meaning is not changed, but the style is informal.

Comment: There are several things to be said about it, including that in rap or rap-type lyrics it reflects American Black English (aka AAVE). The Weeknd, who is Black though Canadian, would be using that dialect. It is not for rhythmical purposes and is not technically wrong in AAVE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "she don't" sometimes considered correct form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108285/is-she-dont-sometimes-considered-correct-form) Also [What is the purpose of using "don't" instead of "doesn't" in this phrase: "But she don't know you like I know you Slim"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/) and ['He don't have knowledge ' vs 'He doesn't have knowledge'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34571/) and many more.

Comment: It can be AAVE but the example in the linked question is She Don't Know Me by Bon Jovi, a white rock band from New Jersey. The New York-born Hispanic singer Jennifer Lopez had a hit with Love Don't Cost a Thing. So it's quite a bit wider than AAVE.